# Combine stdout and stderr into a single node.js stream

Tags: node.js, stream, stdout, stderr, io.js

I want to combine stdout and stderr of a child process into a single, intermediate stream which I can then consume and do processing on.

Is this possible with the standard API's?

(I realize there are subtleties around interleaving the two streams, and I would need them to be only interleaved on line endings for this to work. i.e. writing a line to stdout or stderr should be an atomic operation).

Comment: I'm still looking to solve the same issue :/